# Trouble in querying data

Tags: query

I'm having difficulty in retrieving data from tables.
Bellow is the scenario I'm stuck at.

`TableA`

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | DEF |
| 3 | GHI |
| 4 | JKL |

`TableB`

| Id | TableA_Id | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X |
| 2 | 2 | Y |
| 3 | 0 | Z |

`TableC`

| Id | TableA_Id | Something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | XXX |
| 2 | 1 | XXX |
| 3 | 1 | XXX |
| 4 | 2 | XXX |
| 5 | 2 | XXX |
| 6 | 3 | XXX |
| 7 | 3 | XXX |
| 8 | 4 | XXX |
| 9 | 4 | XXX |

`TableA` joins With `TableB` by `TableA_Id` column, the only difference is that where there is no reference of `TableA` id then we are supposed to return the row with `TableA_Id = 0` from `TableB`.

`Required Output`

| Name | Tag | Something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | X | XXX |
| ABC | X | XXX |
| ABC | X | XXX |
| DEF | Y | XXX |
| DEF | Y | XXX |
| GHI | Z | XXX |
| GHI | Z | XXX |
| JKL | Z | XXX |
| JKL | Z | XXX |

Comment: I think you're missing something in your description. There's no reference to `TableC`. Also, please post what you have attempted

Comment: `TableC` just contains some data with respect to `TableA`. I'm trying to get the data by joining these 3 tables as in `output` table

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! In future, could you please provide your table  structures as DDL (CREATE TABLE x (...) and your data as DML (INSERT INTO x VALUES (...))... it eliminates duplication of effort on behalf of those trying to help you and provides a single source of truth for anyone attempting a solution. Also, in this situation, standard SQL worked, but there are **many** times when an answer is RDBMS (Oracle, PosgreSQL...) **and** server version (Oracle - 18c, 11g.. PG - 10, 12, 13...) - so you should include those in your tags and/or in the text of  your question).

Comment: Sure @Vérace, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.name,
       COALESCE(t2.tag, t3.tag) tag,
       t4.something
FROM tableA t1
LEFT JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.id = t2.TableA_Id
JOIN tableB t3 ON t3.TableA_Id = 0
JOIN tableC t4 ON t1.id = t4.TableA_Id
```

`TableB` must contain only one row with `TableB.TableA_Id = 0`. If not then use

```sql
SELECT t1.name,
       COALESCE(t2.tag, t3.tag) tag,
       t4.something
FROM tableA t1
LEFT JOIN tableB t2 ON t1.id = t2.TableA_Id
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT *
             FROM tableB 
             WHERE TableA_Id = 0
             -- ORDER BY something, for example, by `Id`
             LIMIT 1 ) t3
JOIN tableC t4 ON t1.id = t4.TableA_Id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bbdf0e06bc2af5ca79f8e4587619e6b)

Comment: Thank you sir. This worked